# get classpath dependency in custom gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have to declare dependency for my custom plugin in `buildscript`

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath files (["project/path/to/compiled/classes"])

        classpath ("com.project.plugin:custom-plugin:${pluginVersion}")
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get them somehow inside plugin class

```
public class PluginClass implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getExtensions().create("pluginConfig", PluginExtension.class);
        project.getTasks().create("plugin", PluginTask.class);
    }

}
```

or pass them using extension? Something like:

```
porject.getDependencies().create(classpath_dependency)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access both `dependencies` and `configurations` via `project` instance:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: LolPlugin

class LolPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  public void apply(Project p) {
    p.buildscript.dependencies.each {
      println it
    }
    p.buildscript.configurations.classpath.each {
      println it
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But I am using `java` and not `groovy` for a plugin and there you can just all `buildscript().configurations().classpath`

Comment: Ok, doesn't matter what language it is. You can access required artifact with the code (or similar when it comes java) that I provided.